RRF search in elasticsearch giving problem
GET example-index/_search
{
    "retriever": {
        "rrf": {
            "retrievers": [
                {
                    "standard": {
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "text": "rrf"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "knn": {
                        "field": "vector",
                        "query_vector": [3],
                        "k": 5,
                        "num_candidates": 5
                    }
                }
            ],
            "window_size": 5,
            "rank_constant": 1
        }
    },
    "size": 3,
    "aggs": {
        "int_count": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}


This is the exact code snippet I used in kibana, from the official elasticsearch documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rrf.html#rrf-api, but it is giving me the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [retriever].",
        "line": 2,
        "col": 18
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [retriever].",
    "line": 2,
    "col": 18
  },
  "status": 400
}

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
I was expexting this snippet to run as it's copied directly from the official documentation

It's because of your Elasticsearch version below than 8.14.0. See the followings notes from official documentation.

A retriever is an abstraction that was added to the Search API in
8.14.0.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/retrievers-overview.html

Sure. Thanks, it was indeed the problem, fixed it by upgrading the es.
